# Relating the coefficients of Laurent series to that of power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, entire-functions

> Let $f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be an entire function. If $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}b_nz^n$ is the Laurent series of $\frac{f(z+1)}{z}$ centered on $z=0,$ show that $$b_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\binom{k}{n+1}a_k, n \ge -1.$$

$\frac{f(z+1)}{z} = \sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}b_nz^n \to f(z+1) =\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}b_nz^{n+1}$

I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Also, $f(z+1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z+1)^n$. Use the binomial theorem here, and go through the tedious process of comparing coefficients. I'm sure things will work out.

Comment: Hi. Your title isn't descriptive, please aim to use descriptive titles

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the binomial theorem,  $$(1+z)^k=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn z^n\overset{\color{blue}*}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom kn z^n$$.

So we get $$\dfrac {f(z+1)}z=\dfrac {\sum_{k\ge0}a_k(1+z)^k}z=\dfrac {\sum_{k\ge0}a_k(\sum_{n\ge0}\binom kn z^n)}z=\sum_k\sum_n a_k\binom kn z^{n-1}=\sum_n\sum_k a_k\binom kn z^{n-1}=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \sum_{k\ge0}a_k\binom k{n+1}z^n\overset{\color{blue}*}=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\binom k{n+1}z^n$$,

$\color {blue}*$ because of the convention that for $k\lt n$, we have $\binom kn=0$.